# Why does teachings of great saints of India are mostly scam like say example jeeva.ddns.net

Tags: marriage

If you open the above link which states that its jeeva ddns net which is constructed with ipaddress of that of the bank, which is not easy for manipulation.
However, people can still access the link and can access the bank with this link.
Similarly saints who are fake have fake chakras they have fake intensions. They teach fake principles.
Hence they try to destroy the rep of the society as a whole and Hinduism in total.

This people should be punished by Kalki devo.

Pirasanth Sri Kalki Devo!

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this question is not genuine nor seeking any Hinduism specific answers, but a veiled attempt at promoting the website mentioned in the question, and also suggesting violence and murder.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because what is this a question? Like I am genuinely trying to comprehend what is being asked here. It seems the person here confused question with statement and said fake sages should be punished. Which is an opinion based statement based on who is classified as fake sage? I think mods should also ask this person to review the rules and how a StackExchange works. We are a QnA site not a propaganda and make bold statements platform.